# Save arrays in Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

Suppose I want to have a data schema: every user can have many laptops, and some laptops are available some are not.
I hope that I can get some schema like,

```
User
| userId: 1
| laptops:
   | laptopId: 1  available: true  //default
   | laptopId: 2  available: true
```

How can I define such schema?
The following is not correct:

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: String,
    index: { unique: true }
  },
  laptops: {
    laptopId: String,
    available: Boolean
  }
});
```

How to define this in the Mongoose in node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply use square brackets, like in this example:

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: String,
    index: { unique: true }
  },
  laptops: [{
    laptopId:{
        type: String
    },
    available: {
        type: Boolean
    }
  }]
});
```

Check the [official docs for allowed SchemaTypes.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)