# Array in User Schema - mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

After building an app using the MERN Stack and finished a simple CRUD API for the *items* of the users I wanted to add a '*categories*' property to the user model which he then can add to his items...

To explain the app I planned to attach some default data i.e *categories* to each user while posting his data to MongoDB. Unfortunately, I am failing to 'post' those categories to the database.

Here are different request and schema combinations I have tried out

1. As its own schema

user route

```
const User = require("../models/User")

// @route     POST api/users
// @desc      Regiter a user
// @access    Public
router.post(
  "/",
  [
    check("name", "Please add name")
      .not()
      .isEmpty(),
    check("email", "Please include a valid email").isEmail(),
    check(
      "password",
      "Please enter a password with 6 or more characters"
    ).isLength({ min: 6 })
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() })
    }

    const { name, email, password } = req.body
    console.log(categories)
    try {
      let user = await User.findOne({ email })

      if (user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "User already exists" })
      }

      user = new User({
        name,
        email,
        password,
      })

      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)

      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)

      await user.save()

      const payload = {
        user: {
          id: user.id
        }
      }

      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        config.get("jwtSecret"),
        {
          expiresIn: 360000
        },
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) throw err
          res.json({ token })
        }
      )
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message)
      res.status(500).send("Server Error")
    }
  }
)

module.exports = router
```

request in AuthState

```
    // Register User
      const register = async formData => {
        console.log(formData)
        const expandedFormData = {
          ...formData,
          categories: [
            { name: "Testcategory1", test: 1 },
            { name: "Testcategory2", test: 2 }
          ]
        }
        const config = {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        }
        try {
          const res = await axios.post("/api/users", expandedFormData, config)
          console.log(expandedFormData)
          dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
          })
          loadUser()
        } catch (err) {
          dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_FAIL,
            payload: err.response.data.msg
          })
        }
      }
```

schema

```
        const mongoose = require("mongoose")

        const categorieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
          label: String,
          test: Number
        })

        const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
          name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          },
          email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
          },
          password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          },
          date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
          },
          categories: [categorieSchema]
        })

        module.exports = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema)
```

2.
request in AuthState

```
....

const expandedFormData = {
      ...formData,
      categories: [{ name: "Testcategory1" }, { name: "Testcategory2" }]
    }

....
```

schema

```
....

categories: [
    {
      name: String
    }
  ]

....
```

3.
request in AuthState

schema

same as 2.

```
....

categories: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ]
....
```

4.
request

schema

same as 2.

```
....

  categories: [String]

....
```

I've also read these threads but they did not provide new information:
- [Mongoose schema array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56620235/mongoose-schema-array-of-objects)
- [Save arrays in Mongoose schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288435/save-arrays-in-mongoose-schema)

The full application can be viewed at https://github.com/mortizw/Repio-2.0
Next to some ideas on how to make this model work, I would be happy about some tips on how to iteratively test /approach such a 'schema-problem' as you can with console logging something.

Comment: Can you post how your backend is `saving users?`

Comment: Schema `const categorieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
          name: String,
          test: Number
        })` && `categories: [categorieSchema]` should work, Are other fields in the same request apart `categories` are being updated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating `new User`, you are not passing `Categories` that's why its not being saved.

First of all this Schema will work perfectly fine

```
categories: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ]
```

Then you need to update your `user route` to this

```
const { name, email, password,categories } = req.body

user = new User({
        name,
        email,
        password,
        categories
      })
```

Also make sure you only pass `name` in categories from frontend because your schema only have `name`.

Your frontend should be like this

```
const expandedFormData = {
          ...formData,
          categories: [
            { name: "Testcategory1"},
            { name: "Testcategory2"}
          ]
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I could also just add the defaults in: user = new User({
        name,
        email,
        password,
        categories: [{ name: "Testcategory1" }, { name: "Testcategory2" }]
      })

Comment: Yea that would work as well! As long as Schema is correct